# Download the calendar display as a CSV/XL File

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/) on my web app and I'm trying to find out if there's some functionality to download the calendar for a month as a .CSV or XL file.  Similar to table export on the bootstrap table?

I can't find anything on google or the documentation. Thanks for any help.

Comment: by "download the calendar" do you actually mean "download the list of events"? ...because it's very difficult to see how you could represent all the visual aspects of the calendar in a CSV file.

Comment: Anyway no there's nothing built into fullCalendar to do that. But then again there needn't be really - in most real-life implementations the list of events actually comes from a data store somewhere, usually on a server. So actually the way to implement this requirement is to write some server-side code which allows the list of events to be downloaded in the format of your choice.

Comment: On the other hand if you've added events to the calendar client-side and they aren't (yet) stored anywhere server-side, you could get them by running `calendar.getEvents()` and then write some other JS code to export that array to CSV and offer it for download (you can find separate examples of that online already I think, if you search, it's not specific to fullCalendar once you've got the simple array of data).

Comment: Was any of this helpful to you?